# Module to do an action based on content type user sees

Tags: nodes, database

I would like to achieve, for my custom module, this behavior:

1. It triggers only when user sees the node of some content type
2. It does a calculation based on field present in that content type
   (it checks the values of taxonomy term assigned to that node)
3. It prepares a variable based on calculation (it might be a complex query)
4. article.tpl.php is injected with the content of that variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Drupal 7 you can do all of this in [`hook_node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7), e.g.

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  // Check the node type and that the user is viewing a full node page
  if ($node->type == 'article' && $view_mode == 'full') { 
    // Get some field values from the node
    $field_items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_name');

    // Get the first field value.
    $first_field_item = array_shift($field_items);

    // The index will depend on the type of field; for taxonomy term refs it's 'tid'
    $value = $first_field_item['tid']; 

    // Perform some complex operation on the value.
    $new_value = MYMODULE_complex_op($value);

    // Add the new value to the node content, to be found in the $content array
    // in node--article.tpl.php
    $node->content['my_new_value'] = array(
      '#markup' => $new_value
    );
  }
}
```

In your template file you'll be able to call `print render($content['my_new_value']);` to output the variable to the page.

Obviously that'll need some adjusting for your own needs but hopefully it'll help.

Comment: Thanks Clive, this is gold worth. And will help migrating my code from templates to more appropriate place as suggested in previous questions/answers!